# Is OpenCart or WordPress responding with 404 error for /blog/sitemap-misc.xml?

Tags: wordpress, opencart, sitemap.xml

I am using **OpenCart v.1.5.6.5_rc** for an e-Shop and **WordPress v.4.1** for the e-Shop's blog.

I am a little bit confused on which of the two is responding with a 404 error for the blog's sitemap-misc.xml which is generated from the WordPress plugin **Google XML Sitemaps** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/).
Before using this plugin, I was using **WordPress SEO by Yoast** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) to generated the sitemap xml (for the blog) and I thought that was causing the 404 error, but it wasn't!

My structure is

```
-admin  
-blog/sitemap.xml (/blog/sitemap-misc.xml, /blog/sitemap-tax-post_tag.xml, /blog/sitemap-pt-post-2015-01.xml etc)  
-catalog  
-download  
-image  
-system  
-vqmod  
sitemap.xml (OpenCart: Extensions -> Product Feeds) - works fine
```

What confuses me more is that the /blog/sitemap.xml works, but the analysis of the /blog/sitemap.xml

```
-blog/sitemap.xml  
      sitemap-misc.xml  
      sitemap-tax-post_tag.xml  
      sitemap-pt-post-2015-01.xml
```

fails with a General HTTP error: 404 not found!

Actually, if I use the full path on my browser http://www.example.com/blog/sitemap-misc.xml, OpenCart respondes with a 404 error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: @GavinSimpson, do you mean using something like this - http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/help/#P221_root ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use that, because on the root folder sitemap.xml already exists (generated by OpenCart). An option would be, first to change the name of the /blog/sitemap.xml for example to /blog/sitemap-blog.xml and then move it to the root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was not caused either by **OpenCart** or **WordPress (core)**.

The **W3 Total Cache** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) WordPress plugin that I am using was causing the 404 errors!

I had checked the option in `Performance -> Browser Cache`

Do not process 404 errors for static objects with WordPress.
Reduce server load by allowing the web server to handle 404 (not found) errors for static files (images etc).
**If enabled - you may get 404 File Not Found response for some files generated on-the-fly** by WordPress plugins. You may add those file URIs to 404 error exception list below to avoid that.

```
# BEGIN W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|sitemap(_index)?\.xml(\.gz)?|[a-z0-9_\-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml(\.gz)?)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
```

So, when I unchecked that option my problem was resolved!

I guess I could just remove this line
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|sitemap(_index)?\.xml(\.gz)?|[a-z0-9_\-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml(\.gz)?)`
from the /blog/.htaccess file to reduce server load.